# Use of に in 「私には本物の若殿様がわかります」

Tags: grammar, particle-に, potential-form

## English

What function is に serving in this sentence (the speaker has been asked to pick out the real lord from a group of people):

> 私**に**は本物の若殿様がわかります
>
> I know who the real young lord is

It seems to me that the sentence would make perfect sense without に.

## Japanese

この文の「に」の役割はなんですか？（話し手は少数の人から本物の若殿を選び出すように言われました）

> 私**に**は本物の若殿様がわかります
>
> I know who the real young lord is

私には、「に」がなくても意味は変わらないように思えますが、どうなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

わかる is a potential verb.  Potential verbs sometimes take に or には to contrast or emphasize their subjects. So 私にはわかります means ‘I know it while others probably do not.’ Examples are:

> 彼**にできる**ことなら私**に**も**できる**。 I can do what he can do.
>
> あなた**に**私の気持ちが**わかる**？ Do you know how I feel?
>
> あの子**に**は幽霊が**見える**んだ。 That kid sees ghosts (while we don't).

Comment: I think I understand, but can you explain why @l'électeur said "To me, that sentence makes very little sense without the に"? You seem to be suggesting that the に is optional.

Comment: Both 私に正体がわかること and 私が正体がわかること work.

Comment: Does the contrastive/emphasis nature of には also apply to topics that are not potential verbs, and how can you tell if the には is contrasting or emphasizing? By looking at the context?

Answer (score 8):

After a bit of research I've tentatively convinced myself that this is the answer:

わかります is acting as a passive verb 'to be known' rather than 'to know' or 'to understand'. In which case に is marking the agent of the action, so the sentence literally translates as 'the real young lord is known **by** me.

Without に it would become 'I understand the real  young lord' which is a totally different meaning.

Comment: This is my basic understanding as well. You'd need to use 私は若殿様の正体がわかります or a similar rephrase if you wanted 私は. That said, I haven't figured out how to really explain this well... it's a confusing area.

Comment: I feel like there's also a strongly contrastive element to the は here -- the near direct implication *and not by others*.

Answer (score -1):

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/167736/meaning/m0u/
>     《格助詞「に」＋係助詞「は」》
>
> １． 「に」の付いた部分を強める意を表す。　「僕―わかっている」　「ここ―ない」　「わざわざ出向く―当たらない」

That's all that's in the dictionary, which says 「は」 just adds emphasis.

私に本物の若殿様がわかります
私には本物の若殿様がわかります

I don't know.　 私には分かる、鳥には見える、犬には聞こえる・・・　These seem kind of special to me.　 I like Naho's "Potential verbs"　explanation.

<sub>「僕に出来る」「僕には出来る」だったら、just adds emphasis.で説明できるようだが。</sub> 
 <sub>「分かる」が「受け身」だという説明にも何だか捨て難いものが有るな。</sub>

しかし本題は「に」なんですね！

> [Why is には used in this sentence instead of は?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39861/16344)
>   　なぜ殺されたのか君には分からないのですか?

- 君は分かるか？　「Do you understand?」
- 君に分かるか？　（この「に」は何なんだ？）
- 君には分かるか？　Just emphasis of the above.

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/
>   ６． 動作・作用の行われる対象・相手を表す。「人―よくかみつく犬」「友人―伝える」
>   10． 受け身・使役の相手・対象を表す。「犬―かまれた」「巣箱を子供たち―作らせる」
>   11． 比較・割合の基準や、比較の対象を表す。「君―似ている」「一日―三回服用する」

（この「に」は何なんだ？）　I could not choose between the three candidates and gave up.  I decided to ask Mr. Niwa :

> http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/04dousibun.html のキャッシュです。
>   　10．　彼には子どもはありません。
>   　11．　私にはそれが聞こえましたが、彼には聞こえなかったようです。
>
> 以上のような、能力・所有などを表す動詞とともに使われる「Ｎに」があります。主体、あるいは所有者とすることも考えられますが、「抽象的な場所」としておきます。

Mr. Niwa's answer :　  「抽象的な場所」  ！ ！ ！

> http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/07kakujosi.html のキャッシュです。
>   7.3  　に
>
> ② 存在の場所 （物理的・抽象的）　家にいる、 結論に問題がある、 この病気は子どもに多い

---

「抽象的な場所」　ねぇ・・・　　まぁ、落ち着いて考えてみると、（私にも）かなり納得できるな。

「それが聞こえた」　というのを意思とは関係なしに自動的に起きる自然現象のようにとらえて、　「私にそれが聞こえた」　と、　その現象が起きる 「抽象的な場所」 を示す。

「君に分かるか？」 「君には分かるか？」　　私には分かる、鳥には見える、犬には聞こえる・・・　
こういうのも、意思や努力とは無関係に起きる事象であると見ることもできる。

そう私には感じられる。　 <sub>（　←　これは　「受け身」　か？　）</sub>

Comment: `そう私には感じられる。（←これは「受け身」か？）`←　助動詞「れる・られる」の「受け身・可能・自発・尊敬」のなかの「自発」に当てはまるのではないかと。